# What environment is expected by `if(typeof exports === 'object')` in UMD definition

Tags: javascript, webpack, amd, commonjs, umd

Webpack generates the following UMD definition:

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    // this is CommonJS/Node
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory();
    // this is AMD
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define([], factory);
    // what is this environment or standard?
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')        <------------- ???
        exports["rx-core-libs"] = factory();
    // Window/Global
    else
        root["rx-core-libs"] = factory();
})
```

My question is what is this standard or environment for?

```
else if(typeof exports === 'object')
```

It's like CommonJS but without `module`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5826#issuecomment-341347925) by @sokra:

> There are two different CommonJs specs. CommonJS strict has only
>   exports and no module.exports. Node.js added module.exports but that's
>   not part of the original spec.

[This commonjs](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) spec states that:

> - In a module, there is a free variable called "exports", that is an
>     object that the module may add its API to as it executes. **Modules must
>     use the "exports" object as the only means of exporting**.

That's why webpack exports dependencies through `exports` object:

```
else if(typeof exports === 'object')
    exports["rx-core-libs"] = factory()
```